# Definition of a regular map of projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\BP}{\mathbb P} \newcommand{\BA}{\mathbb A}$
I'm following Harris' Algebraic Geometry, where a regular map $\phi: X\to \BP^n$, with $X\subseteq \BP^m$ a quasi-projective variety, is defined as follows:

- $\phi: X\to \BP^n$ is regular if (1) it is continuous and (2) the restrictions $\phi_i: \phi^{-1}(V_i) \to \BA^n$ are regular, where $V_i \cong \BA^n \subseteq \BP^n$ form the standard cover $V_i = \{[X_0...X_n]: X_i\neq 0\}$. This necessitates the definition:
- $\phi: X \to \BA^n$ is regular if it is regular in each affine coordinate. This necessitates the definition:
- $f: X \to K$ is regular if the restrictions $f_i: X \cap U_i \to K$ are regular, where $U_i \cong \BA^m \subseteq \BP^m$ form the standard cover of $\BP^m$. This necessitates the definition:
- $f: U \to K$, where $Y \subseteq \BA^m$ is an affine variety and $U \subseteq Y$ is an open subset, is regular if for every point $p\in U$, there exists a neighborhood $W$ of $p$ where $f$ equals a quotient $g/h$ of polynomials $g, h\in K[z_1...z_m]$ and $h \neq 0$.

He also mentions that if $X \subseteq \BP^m$ is a projective variety, then if we have a map $X\to \BP^n$ specified by an $(n+1)$-tuple of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree with no common zeros on $X$, then this map is a regular map; but this does not describe all maps of projective varieties to projective space.

I understand all the pieces of this definition but I am still confused about it intuitively. Is there a more cohesive way to define a regular map from $X$ to $\BP^n$ without jumping through these affine covers and coordinates? Furthermore, if I am given that a map $\phi: X\to \BP^n$ is regular, what can I really say about it, i.e. what really is the datum of a regular map? Is it true that $\phi$ is locally given by an $(n+1)$-tuple of homogeneous polynomials? If so, can this local description be made finite, so that there is a finite open cover of $X$ on which $f$ can be specified by homogeneous polynomials?

Comment: Yes, but it requires a bit more machinery to state. Namely, maps to $\mathbb{P}^n$ correspond to a line bundle on $X$ together with $n+1$ globally generating sections.